# Struts 2 - How to get beanList from JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2

I'm using struts2 + spring DI to autowired beans. i want to create a form that handling save multiple rows. the idea is create a bean inside a bean.

CreatePeopleAction.java

```
public class CreatePeopleAction extends BaseAction {

@Autowired
private PeopleManager PeopleManager;

@Autowired
private PeopleCreateBean peopleCreateBean;

@Autowired
private java.util.ArrayList<PeopleItemsBean> peopleItemsBean;


public String create() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    result = peopleManager.createPeople(peopleCreateBean);
    if (result.get(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE) != null) 
        setMessage(result.get(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE).toString());

    return result.get(Constants.ACTION_RESULT).toString();
}
  --setter --getter
}
```

PeopleCreateBean.java

```
@Component

    public class PeopleCreateBean {

    private List<PeopleItemsBean> peopleItemsBean;

    private ArrayList<MasterCode> nationalityOptions = null;
    private ArrayList<MasterCode> genderOptions = null;
    private ArrayList<MasterCode> salutationOptions = null;
    private ArrayList<MasterCode> designationOptions = null;

    private String name;
    private Integer designation;
    private String passportNo;
    private Integer nationality;
    private Integer gender;
    private Integer salutation;

    --setter getter

    }
```

PeopleItemsBean.java

```
public class PeopleItemsBean extends java.util.ArrayList {

private String name;
private String designation;
private String passportNo;
private String nationality;
private String gender;
private String salutation;

    --setter --getter

}
```

PeopleManagerImpl.java

```
@Service("peopleManager")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
public class PeopleManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<People, Integer> 
implements PeopleManager {

    PeopleDao peopleDao;

@Autowired
private MasterCodeManager masterCodeManager;

@Autowired
public PeopleManagerImpl(PeopleDao peopleDao) {
    super(peopleDao);
    this.peopleDao = peopleDao;
}

private People setPeople(PeopleCreateBean peopleCreateBean) throws Exception {

    People People = null;

    if(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean()!=null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().isEmpty() && peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().size() >0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().size(); i++){

            People = new People(); 

            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPrCompaniesId() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPrCompaniesId().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setPrCompaniesId(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPrCompaniesId());
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getName() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getName().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setName(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getName());
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getDesignation() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getDesignation().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setDesignation(Integer.parseInt(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getDesignation()));
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPassportNo() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPassportNo().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setPassportNo(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getPassportNo());
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getNationality() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getNationality().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setNationality(Integer.parseInt(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getNationality()));
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getGender()!= null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getGender().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setGender(Integer.parseInt(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getGender()));
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getSalutation() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getSalutation().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setSalutation(Integer.parseInt(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getSalutation()));
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getEffectiveDate() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getEffectiveDate().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setEffectiveDate(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getEffectiveDate());
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getExpiryDate() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getExpiryDate().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setExpiryDate(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getExpiryDate());
            }
            if (peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getStatus() != null && !peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getStatus().equals(Constants.STRING_EMPTY)) {
                People.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(peopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getStatus()));
            }

        }


    }

    return people;
}

//trying to save..iteration.

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
@Override
public Map<String, Object> createPeople(PeopleCreateBean PeopleCreateBean) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put(Constants.ACTION_RESULT, Action.SUCCESS);
    try {

        if(PeopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean()!=null && !PeopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().isEmpty() && PeopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().size() >0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<PeopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().size(); i++){

                People People = queryPrPeople(PeopleCreateBean.getPeopleItemsBean().get(i).getName());
                if (prPeople == null ) {
                            prPeopleDao.insert(setPrPeople(PeopleCreateBean));
                            result.put(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE, BLConstant.USERCREATIONSTATUS_SUCCESS);
                            result.put(Constants.ACTION_RESULT, Action.SUCCESS);
                } else {
                    result.put(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE, BLConstant.USERCREATIONSTATUS_FAILED_USEREXISTS);
                }

            }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.put(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE, BLConstant.USERCREATIONSTATUS_FAILED);
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

 --setter --getter

}
```

AddPeople.jsp

```
<s:form id="frmPeopleAdd" action="createPeopleCreateAction" method="post" validate="false" theme="css_xhtml">
<s:include value="People_tab.jsp"/>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <s:set name="varMessage" value="PeopleCreateBean.txtMessage"/>
    <s:hidden name="PeopleCreateBean.PeopleItemsBean"></s:hidden>
    <s:if test="%{#varMessage != null && #varMessage != ''}">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="alertMessage" align="left"><s:property value="PeopleCreateBean.txtMessage"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </s:if>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="95%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td class="mainheader">People</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%" align="center" id="myTable" class="order-list">
       <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldname">No</td>
            <td class="fieldname">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="fieldname">Nationality <span class="mandatoryMessage">*</span></td>
            <td class="fieldname">NRIC/Passport No <span class="mandatoryMessage">*</span></td>
            <td class="fieldname">Salutation</td>
            <td class="fieldname">Name <span class="mandatoryMessage">*</span></td>
            <td class="fieldname">Designation <span class="mandatoryMessage">*</span></td>
            <td class="fieldname">Gender <span class="mandatoryMessage">*</span></td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <s:if test="PeopleItemsBean != null">
            <%int i=0;%>

            <s:iterator value="PeopleItemsBean"  status="stat" >
            <%i++;%>

            <tr>
            <td width="5%" class="fieldContent"><span><s:property value="%{#stat.count}"/></span></td>

            <td width="5%" class="fieldContent"></td>

            <td class="fieldContent">

                <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue=" Please Select " list="PeopleCreateBean.nationalityOptions" listKey="id" listValue="masterCodeMembersDesc" name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].nationality" />

            </td>

            <td width="15%" class="fieldContent"><s:textfield name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].passportNo" size="20" style="width:90%"/></td>

             <td class="fieldContent">
                <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue=" Please Select " list="PeopleCreateBean.salutationOptions" listKey="masterCodeMember" listValue="masterCodeMembersDesc" name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].salutation" />
            </td>

            <td width="20%" class="fieldContent"><s:textfield name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].name" size="20" style="width:90%"/></td>

            <td class="fieldContent">
                <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue=" Please Select " list="PeopleCreateBean.designationOptions" listKey="id" listValue="masterCodeMembersDesc" name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].designation" />
            </td>

            <td class="fieldContent">
                <s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue=" Please Select " list="PeopleCreateBean.genderOptions" listKey="id" listValue="masterCodeMembersDesc" name="PeopleItemsBean[%{#stat.index}].gender" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </s:iterator>


         </s:if>

           --and the rest.....
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="People" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>

        <action name="*PeopleCreateAction" method="{1}"
                class="com.ox.people.action.PeopleCreateAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>  
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/peopleAdd.tiles</result>
        </action>

    </package>
 </struts>
```

I got error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.XWorkList cannot be cast to com.ox.people.action.model.PeopleItemsBean
    at com.ox.people.service.PeopleManagerImpl.createPeople(PeopleManagerImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createPeople(Unknown Source)
    at com.ox.people.action.PeopleCreateAction.create(PeopleCreateAction.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
[18/10/2013 16:26:39.204] ERROR PeopleManagerImpl - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.XWorkList cannot be cast to com.ox.people.action.model.PeopleItemsBean
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

How to get the bean (PeopleItemsBean) from jsp and save into database ? 
any idea ?

Thanks

MRizq

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Why do you need your `PeopleItemsBean` to extend `ArrayList`?

Comment: because, i need to iterate in jsp page.